# GET HTTP request to update a textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm working on an app that need to do a GET request to update a TextView on screen, now im doing it with a button but i need to update the textview constantly. what's the best way or practice to do it? here the code of the request, the button just call it and put the response string on the TextView.

```
protected void getEquiposHTTP() {
    //Método GET HTTP al servicio Cloudant IBM para las credenciales dadas
    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("data")
            .appendPath("data")
            .appendPath("data")
            .appendPath("data")
            .appendPath("data")
            .appendPath("data")
            .appendQueryParameter("data", "data");
    String myUrl = builder.build().toString();

    byte[] encoding = Base64.encodeBase64(("data" + ":" + "data").getBytes());
    String encodedString = new String(encoding);

    final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(myUrl)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString)
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            String mMessage = e.getMessage().toString();
            call.cancel();
            Log.e(TAG, "Problem at HTTP connection and call.cancel() executed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    addToListEquipos(response.body().string());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Problem at response of HTTP conection, response.isSuccessful() = true then try{} fail");
                }
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Best way would be to use `FireBase real time database`. Update you database using the `HTTP request` after certain intervals and on the app side, `observe` changes in the firebase database node. In this way, your `textView` would be updated without constantly making HTTP request after each interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by running a thread which keeps hitting the server in small intervals to fetch the new data and update the ui. This is not the appropriate way to do things because app will keep hitting the server again and again even in case of no update.

The second way (which is more preferred one but needs extra efforts) is by using something like Push-notification, [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)
 or XMPP server. This way your server will tell the client app about the new data.

**From the official site of Firebase Realtime Database**

> The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted database. Data is stored as JSON and synchronized in realtime to every connected client. When you build cross-platform apps with our iOS, Android, and JavaScript SDKs, all of your clients share one Realtime Database instance and automatically receive updates with the newest data.

Comment: Thank! it was really helpful !